# Cube.js <QueryBuilder> default value of timeDimensions

Tags: reactjs, query-builder, cube.js

I am using the Cube.js react client to change the default timeDimension, dateRange, and granularity of my Query.

`import { QueryBuilder } from '@cubejs-client/react'`

here is what timeDimension property on the JSON Query should look like,

```
timeDimensions: [
          {
            dimension: 'EMSHistory.startTime',
            dateRange: 'Today',
            granularity: "day"
          },
        ]
```

The default query is what I see in Cube.js Server Logs. with the default settings of **no dateRange property**, which means **default date range is all time**, and **granularity of "day"**.

**this return data of all time, grouped by day, while I only want Today's data.**

```
{
  "measures": [
    "EMSHistory.runDurationSum"
  ],
  "timeDimensions": [
    {
      "dimension": "EMSHistory.startTime",
      "granularity": "day"
    }
  ],
  "order": [
    {
      "id": "EMSHistory.startTime",
      "desc": false
    }
  ],
  "filters": [],
  "timezone": "Asia/Taipei",
  "dimensions": []
}
```

**The Query I want should look like this:**

```
{
  "measures": [
    "EMSHistory.runDurationSum"
  ],
  "timeDimensions": [
    {
      "dimension": "EMSHistory.startTime",
      "dateRange": [
        "2021-10-21T00:00:00.000",
        "2021-10-21T23:59:59.999"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "order": [
    {
      "id": "EMSHistory.startTime",
      "desc": false
    }
  ],
  "filters": [],
  "timezone": "Asia/Taipei",
  "dimensions": []
}
```

below is my code:

```
const ExploreQueryBuilder = ({
  vizState,
  finalTitle,
  customStyle,
  cubejsApi,
  setVizState,
  chartExtra,
  itemId,
}) => (
  <QueryBuilder
    vizState={vizState}
    finalTitle={finalTitle}
    setVizState={setVizState}
    cubejsApi={cubejsApi}
    wrapWithQueryRenderer={false}
    render={({
      validatedQuery,
      isQueryPresent,
      chartType,
      updateChartType,
      measures,
      availableMeasures,
      updateMeasures,
      dimensions,
      availableDimensions,
      updateDimensions,
      segments,
      availableSegments,
      updateSegments,
      filters,
      updateFilters,
      timeDimensions,
      availableTimeDimensions,
      updateTimeDimensions,
    }) => [
        <Row
          type="flex"
          justify="space-around"
          align="top"
          gutter={24}
          style={{
            marginBottom: 12,
          }}
          key="1"
        >
          <Col span={24}>
            <Card>
              <Row
                type="flex"
                justify="space-around"
                align="top"
                gutter={24}
                style={{
                  marginBottom: 12,
                }}
              >
                <Col span={24}>
                  <MemberGroup
                    members={measures}
                    availableMembers={availableMeasures}
                    addMemberName="Measure"
                    updateMethods={updateMeasures}
                  />
                  <Divider type="vertical" />
                  <MemberGroup
                    members={dimensions}
                    availableMembers={availableDimensions}
                    addMemberName="Dimension"
                    updateMethods={updateDimensions}
                  />
                  <Divider type="vertical" />
                  <MemberGroup
                    members={segments}
                    availableMembers={availableSegments}
                    addMemberName="Segment"
                    updateMethods={updateSegments}
                  />
                  <Divider type="vertical" />
                  <TimeGroup
                    members={timeDimensions}
                    availableMembers={availableTimeDimensions}
                    addMemberName="Time"
                    updateMethods={updateTimeDimensions}
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row
                type="flex"
                justify="space-around"
                align="top"
                gutter={24}
                style={{
                  marginBottom: 12,
                }}
              >
                <Col span={24}>
                  <FilterGroup
                    members={filters}
                    availableMembers={availableDimensions.concat(availableMeasures)}
                    addMemberName="Filter"
                    updateMethods={updateFilters}
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row type="flex" justify="space-around" align="top" gutter={24}>
                <Col span={24}>
                  <SelectChartType chartType={chartType} updateChartType={updateChartType} />
                </Col>
              </Row>
              {itemId ? (
                <Row
                  type="flex"
                  justify="flex-end"
                  align="top"
                  gutter={24}
                  style={{
                    marginTop: 12,
                  }}
                >
                  <Button type="primary">
                    <Link to={'/explore'}>
                      <FormattedMessage id={'component.copy'} />
                    </Link>
                  </Button>
                </Row>
              ) : null}
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>,
        <Row type="flex" justify="space-around" align="top" gutter={24} key="2">
          <Col span={24}>
            {isQueryPresent ? (
              <Card
                title={finalTitle}
                headStyle={customStyle.card ? customStyle.card.headStyle : undefined}
                bodyStyle={customStyle.card ? customStyle.card.bodyStyle : undefined}
                key={new Date()}
                style={{
                  minHeight: 420,
                }}
                extra={chartExtra}
              >
                {filters[0] &&
                  filters[0].operator &&
                  (filters[0].values === undefined || filters[0].values.length === 0) ? (
                  <p>
                    <FormattedMessage id={'component.filter-value'} />
                  </p>
                ) : (
                  <ChartRenderer
                    vizState={{
                      query: validatedQuery,
                      chartType,
                    }}
                    customStyle={customStyle}
                    cubejsApi={cubejsApi}
                  />
                )}
              </Card>
            ) : (
              <h2
                style={{
                  textAlign: 'center',
                }}
              >
                <FormattedMessage id={'component.establish'} />
              </h2>
            )}
          </Col>
        </Row>,
      ]
    }
  />
);

ExploreQueryBuilder.propTypes = {
  vizState: PropTypes.object,
  finalTitle: PropTypes.object,
  customStyle: PropTypes.object,
  setVizState: PropTypes.func,
  cubejsApi: PropTypes.object,
  chartExtra: PropTypes.array,
};
ExploreQueryBuilder.defaultProps = {
  vizState: {},
  customStyle: {},
  setVizState: null,
  cubejsApi: null,
  chartExtra: null,
};
export default ExploreQueryBuilder;
```